# common models in django

Tags: python, django

I am new in Django and I don't know how to deal with sharing models problem. For simplicity assume that we have two apps: A1, A2 and one model M1. Now I would like to A1 and A2 are using the same model M1. I probably can put M1 inside A1 and A2 but this is not good idea. How to deal with this ?

Comment: what do you mean be `using the same model` ? How are the relationship defined? Is it a foreign key, or a many to many, or do both contain the fields specified in `m1` ?

Comment: For example i have table User and i want to use it as model in django in A1 and A2. Should i define this model twice in A1 and A2 models.py file or do something else to achieve this ?

Comment: oh.. you just need to import from where it is defined. example `from <file_with_models> import User`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing models between Django apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137287/sharing-models-between-django-apps)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

define `M1` in app `A1` or `A2` and use like this in another app `models.py`:

```
from A1.models import M1
```

Comment: Thanks this is some solution but when I will have 10 apps then i will have to remember where i define this model. Better solution would be some folder where i would put common models.

Comment: @DawidSkrzypczyński yes , `common` directory is best choince.

Comment: But that common directory needs to be a django app or normal directory. Otherwise how will we make migrations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70563345/django-common-model-used-in-several-applications/77359142#77359142