# Django, common model used in several applications

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

In my project, there are applications named "developer" and "startup"

In developer and startup application, i need a table named "languages", which implies that the language developer use and startup use.

So i made model named "languages", But I'm thinking about whether to make this in developer application or startup application, or make a new application and make it in it.

When I made it in developer application, i could use it by importing startup application models.py. But actually, I don't think that the table "languages" is more relevant to application "developler" than "startup".

How should I do?

I referenced [link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137287/sharing-models-between-django-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137287/sharing-models-between-django-apps)

Answer (score 1):

As far I can see from your context: the language model (If even needed) should go to the developer because the developer is the one who closely relates to language, and will mostly consume it in views, and serializer, etc.

**In general, we follow these three basic rules**

1. Keep apps small Each app
2. Does one thing well
3. Keep apps separate so they can be exported and used elsewhere

Just keep these simple basic rules in front of yourself whenever defining a new model in a Django app.

Answer (score 0):

If there are some fields common in every model in every app then we can use the following way to implement them:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
import uuid

# Create your models here.


class BaseModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    inactive = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, db_index=True, editable=False,
                                   on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="%(class)s_created")
    updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, db_index=True, editable=False,
                                   on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="%(class)s_updated")
```

So, Now we can make new model by inheriting the `BaseModel` like blew:

```
class Product(BaseModel):
    """
    Product Model: Represents a product with features and details.
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, help_text='Product name')
    """ The rest of the fields will be the same as you have
    """
```

This way can design your models in your `Django` based project.