# Django relationships between apps: How to keep apps separate?

Tags: django, database-design, django-admin

I need to connect two apps in a Django project, but don't want to import models from the one into the other. Keeping them 'clean' will allow me to reuse them separately later on.

In this particular case, I need a many-to-many relation between two models in these separate apps. One solution would be to create a model in the main project app that defines foreign keys to both. Is this the Django way or is there a better solution?

Comment: If one app requires importing of modules from another app then there is no tidiness in it (because they are dependent).

Comment: some related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4137287, https://stackoverflow.com/q/2054357, https://stackoverflow.com/q/49261290

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for a kind of [Mediator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern). If your apps don't need to know each other, one approach can be write another app that will know both.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought when I said I could put a model in the main project app. But I think I found something better and more Django-esque: [proxy model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models).  That way I can keep the base app clean of any project-related dependencies and thus reusable, and put them instead into a "derived" app with proxy models. And of course, I will need to swap the base app with the derived app in settings/INSTALLED_APPS.

Answer (score 0):

django-profiles, django-sorl, django- all work as a 'many-to-one' type relationship. When you choose to use on of these plugins/apps (and others), you will end up making your designed app dependant on on their presence.

Option 1:
Considering the above...  make one of the apps you intend to design generic enough that the dependency is only 1 way (hence, other apps will depend on it but not the other way around). This is what most django apps already do.

Option 2:
If each of your apps shares a dependency amongst each another, then you'd probably make your life a lot easy to just keep it part of the same app/plug-in.

Comment: thanks - Yes I don't mind if I dirty my project-specific apps, just the generic apps should stay clean. I tested the proxy mechanism and it fits my needs entirely, i.e. I can expand my generic app by the part that depends on the other apps. It's like inheritance for apps without dirtying the underlying data.