# How to divide a django project into applications

Tags: django, django-apps, django-project-architect

I want to know how to divide a project having a hierarchical structure into applications. Let's say that I'm trying to build something like github.com.

In github.com, an account has some repositories, which have some features like code, issues, or pull requests. And those features have references to other features. In this case, which is an application and which is not? At that time, should I put applications in the root directory or in an application directory as sub-applications?

Answer (score 5):

In an ideal world, each app would be independent of the others, or only loosely coupled to the others.  But in many real world situations, there are often so interdependencies that it's hardly worth trying to abstract them.

So, then, in that case.. the best way to separate them is to divide them into functional groups where the majority of the views, models etc in each app are used solely within the app.  So, given your github example, the "issues" could be their own app.  The `issues` app would have specific views that are related solely to displaying, editing and serving (ajax requests, etc) issues, models for storing issues and their ongoing status, templates which are solely responsible for rendering issue views, issue entry for example, issues per user, issues per project, details of a particular issues.  There's actually a lot of issue-specific code.

And yes, by the time you're done, you'll have for example foreign keys from those issue models to user models and to perhaps a commit model, a project model.. many interdependencies that would prevent the `issues` app from working without the presence of other apps.  But logically, when it's time to work on the issue system, you'll know where to go.. because all the issue code is in one place.  All the default issue settings are in `issues/settings.py` for example, all the tables primarily related to issues will be prefixed with the `app_label` eg.  `issues_issue`, `issues_comment`.. etc..

So basically, try to break it up on the basis of core functionality, and minimize the number of dependencies.. or at least, try to avoid circular dependencies.. eg, some apps will have many other apps depending upon them, some will have none.  Try to avoid a deadly embrace.  But, in the end, dependencies will happen.

In some cases, you may be able to implement optional dependencies, eg.. when something happens in App A, Model_A, it should trigger something happening in App B, Model_B.. but only if App B is installed.  There are ways to do this less-closely-coupled behavior, such as Django's signal system

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/

But this is not as reliable as a foreign key, so do not go out of your way to loosely couple things which will never be uncoupled.

Try to divide things into apps on the basis of closely coupled functionality, eg. views that are related to other views.  Put things which all your apps rely upon into your master app or into a library.. and you'll find that your code is much easier to maintain as it grows.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the applications at the level of your manage.py file in your main project, then you can easily run this command: **python manage.py startapp login_app**. Then you can have a structure like so:

```
main_project
     login_app
     codeissues_app
     pullrequests_app
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to create independent apps for every app in your project. I suggest you to follow the `domain driven design`. (google it)

So imagine you are building a ecommerce shop. You would have something like:

```
your_project_folder
   docs
   readme
   static
   your_project
        domain # here you put the models logic
            cart
            products
            payment
            shipping
            tax
        infrastructure # your packages to interface with other services
            paypal
            stripe
        interface 
            rest
            another_rest
        presentation
            public_site
   ...
```

This is just an example of how you can divide the project. Than you must have boundaries. In the domain folder you must group the packages (and so design your model) to not permit cross references.

Interface, Infrastructure and Presentation can access to the Domain.

The Domain should be more stricter.  Have a look here: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html

Anyway this is just the surface of the subject. Depends a lot of what kind of project you are building and what are the requirements. Have a look at the Domain Driven Design.

Comment: I don't use startapp. I just create the app manually where I need them